# How to use Gremlin in Scala script?

Tags: scala, gremlin, janusgraph

I'm trying to use Janusgraph in scala script with tinkerpop 3. I use the gremlin.scala library (https://github.com/mpollmeier/gremlin-scala) but I get an error about HNil (see below). How to use gremlin in scala script and Janusgraph ?

```
import gremlin.scala._
import org.apache.commons.configuration.BaseConfiguration
import org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Graph

object Janus {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new BaseConfiguration()
    conf.setProperty("storage.backend","inmemory")
    val graph = JanusGraphFactory.open(conf)
    val v1 = graph.graph.addV("test")
  }
}
```

Error:(11, 14) Symbol 'type scala.ScalaObject' is missing from the classpath.
This symbol is required by 'trait shapeless.HNil'.
Make sure that type ScalaObject is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
A full rebuild may help if 'HNil.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of scala.
    val v1 = graph.graph.addV("test")

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by 'scala script', but it looks like you're missing many (all?) dependencies. Did you have a look at https://github.com/mpollmeier/gremlin-scala-examples/ ? It contains an example setup for janusgraph.

Comment: By scala script I mean code written in scala. In fact, I have used the dependencies written in your built.sbt file.

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "com.michaelpollmeier" %% "gremlin-scala" % "3.2.4.15",
   "org.janusgraph" % "janusgraph-core" % "0.1.1",
   "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3" % Test,
   "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.3" % Test
)

I have to work offline so I have downloaded the first three dependencies in maven central repository and I have added the dependencies to my project.

Comment: I don't think I can help unless you share a reproducible project setup. as mentioned I'd recommend to clone gremlin-scala-examples as a quick start